# Uso de datos en servidores

Tags: php, mysql, apache, servidor

**Quería saber si hay alguna forma o método de bloquear cualquier dato que no sea del mismo servidor.**

Por ejemplo tengo un archivo php que recoge datos **POST** y **GET** y hace modificaciones a la base de datos. Pero quiero que esas peticiones solo la pueda hacer yo. Se que existe lo de la política de same origin, pero eso solo funciona en los navegadores.

Y el **método de poner contraseña**, no veo muy útil porque se puede ver las peticiones recogiendo el paquete. En f12 network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu servidor, cuando generas el html para mostrar el formulario, generas también un código aleatorio de texto y número que guardas en la variable $_SESSION

ese código lo muestras en el formulario con un input type="hidden" name="nonce" value="codigo_aleatorio"

Cuando recibes el $_POST compruebas si ese value del nonce es el mismo que el que está guardado en $_SESSION, si no es así ese formulario que te enviaron no es de una sesión válida.